# How do baking recipes based on protein powders work?

Tags: baking

This is a recent phenomena on Fitness Youtube I noticed: Making foodds using protein powders in baking. What I don't understand is, wouldn't the proteins from protein powder be not good for baking since they are meant for room temperature? When I tried mixing my Whey in hot water once, it started coagulating.

[Example recipe by Felu-Fit by cooking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-76wTAtoCk)

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'good for baking' – the proteins in a fried egg are certainly in a different state to the raw egg, but that isn't a problem because it's the desired state.

Comment: I've tried to answer in general terms, but if you have a specific recipe in writing  I may be able to expand on  my answer

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "not good for baking"? If you throw raw flour in hot water, it will create a clumpy mess, but raw flour is "good for baking" in any sense I can think of. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @rumtscho A priori it is not clear that a food designed to be used around room temperature is actually safe to eat after heating  to oven temperature. It could be the case that some funny chemistry happens at high temperatures. This is not the case here but that doesn't make the question wrong.

Comment: So it's a safety concern? This isn't something I would ever read into the current formulation of the question.

Comment: I'd say it's more of a general curiosity than a direct safety concern @rumtscho

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing a specific recipe, I strongly suspect that it hydrates the protein powder cold, then heats it up.  You can do this with protein shakes as well, so long as the powder is very well dispersed indeed, and you heat it gently.  I sometimes make a protein hot chocolate recovery drink this way.

Also the protein baking recipes I've seen - not made - tend to add other solid ingredients, such as (ground) nuts and seeds.  These mix with the whey powder and physically block big clumps from forming.

Finally, while there's normally egg to bind, some degree of coagulation of the whey powder is probably needed to help the final product stay together.

Comment: A protein hot chocolate recovery drink sounds excellent and definitely something I will look into for when the weather cools down

Comment: @dbmag9 I use vanilla or chocolate whey powder, with plenty of cocoa powder even if starting from fake chocolate flavour.  As a recovery rather than a protein drink (after long bike rides) using some instant hot chocolate powder is also good.  But do be sure to disperse/hydrate well while cold, then heat or you'll get clumps